# Generalization error of PCA and kernel PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, kernel-trick, mathematical-statistics

I've been recently reading Shawe-Taylor et al. 2005, [On the Eigenspectrum of the Gram Matrix and the Generalization Error of Kernel PCA](http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/259779/1/OnTheEigenspectrumOfTheGramMatrix.pdf), where the authors analyze the squared residual of kernel principal component analysis (kernel PCA, kPCA).

I am wondering if there is any similar theory about the generalization error (in terms of reconstruction error) for standard PCA.

I've searched the literature a little bit, but most of them analyze this problem in terms of the angle between the true eigenvectors (of population covariance matrix) and estimated eigenvectors of (empirical covariance matrix) and in the scenario of sparse PCA.

Comment: +1. Sounds interesting, but is impossible to answer unless one is familiar with Shawe-Taylor et al. paper (because you don't provide any details in your question). I might try to find time to take a look at it one of the following days.

Comment: The paper is quite a tough read for me. But note that standard PCA is a special case of kernel PCA, where the kernel function is simply a dot product. So it seems that you can directly apply all theorems from Shawe-Taylor et al. to the standard PCA case. Would this be enough for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @amoeba. I am not quite sure if the theorems in that paper can be generalized to standard PCA, since all the analysis there is based on the Gram matrix, rather than covariance matrix. As a result, the generalized bound does not depend on the dimension of input space, which is really counter-intuitive.